# Who is the English translator of "The Man Who Wanted to Know" by Dror Mishani if it is a work of translation?

Tags: translation, hebrew-language, dror-mishani, the-man-who-wanted-to-know

I am under the impression Mishani doesn't write in English. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dror_Mishani):

> Haish sheratza ladaat hakol (2015; To be published in English during 2016: The Man who wanted to know)

[This source](https://internationalcrimefiction.org/2015/09/26/israeli-crime-fiction-judgment-and-illustration-by-dror-mishani/) claims:

> Two of his three Inspector Avraham novels have been translated into English: The Missing File (2013) and A Possibility Of Violence (2014). A third, The Man Who Wanted To Know, appeared in Hebrew in May this year and has not yet been translated.

I don't have a copy of *The Man Who Wanted to Know Everything: An Inspector Avraham Avraham Novel* so I'd like to know who did the English translation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Todd Hasak-Lowy

According to [Dror Mishani's own website](https://d-a-mishani.com/):

> – 11 / 2016: “The Man who wanted to know everything” out in the US – and is on PW’s books of the week list with a starred review!
>
> The third Avraham novel, “The Man who wanted to know everything”, is published today in the US (HarperCollins; translated from Hebrew by Todd Hasak-Lowy) – and is on PW’s books of the week list.

And confirmed by a [reviewer and blogger](https://ellisshuman.blogspot.com/2017/02/review-of-man-who-wanted-to-know.html) who read the book:

> We meet Inspector Avraham Avraham for the third time in The Man Who Wanted to Know Everything by D.A. Mishani, translated by Todd Hasak-Lowy (Harper Paperbacks, November 2016).

[Todd Hasak-Lowy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todd_Hasak-Lowy) is a writer, translator, and professor of creative writing and literature. His website is [here](https://www.toddhasaklowy.com/), with a detailed biography on his [About Me page](https://www.toddhasaklowy.com/new-page-2), and a list of [works he's translated](https://www.toddhasaklowy.com/translation) which includes *The Man who wanted to know everything*.

Comment: Check out Hasak-Lowy's "Translation" page: https://www.toddhasaklowy.com/translation